# C# CacheHelpers NullReference

Tags: winforms

I using for C# in WinForm cache this method

```
public static bool IsExist(string key)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] != null;
}
```

But I have NullReferenceError **return** line.
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Most likely `HttpContext.Current` returns `null` because that ["Gets or sets the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx). Since you are in a WinForms app, as you say, you don't have "current HTTP request". Try using the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead.

Comment: Really thank you, I solved my problem with `HttpRuntime`. Thanks :)